Creating a passkey for your apple account?
When I enter my email to sign into https://www.icloud.com/, it shows an option to sign in with a passkey. When I select it, it tries to get a passkey from my password option, and there seems to be no option to create one in Apple account settings, or on the betas on macOS 15 and iOS 18.


Passkeys are created automatically when you have a device with iOS 17/macOS 14 and iCloud Keychain enabled for your iCloud account.
You cannot add passkeys to devices that don't meet these requirements, as there's no way to "create" a passkey for other devices.
